# how can i drive a motor with an inverter providing it's power supply?

Tags: power-supply, inverter, three-phase

I'm trying to drive a gyroscope that needs a 3 phase 400Hz 32v 0.7A power supply. i'm going to  use an inverter to provide  my supply(1phase to 3phase AC: LS-IG5A-0.75kw). i have 2question about it:
 1-can i give a perfect sin wave from an inverter output?or it needs special considerations and circuits?
 2-can i give a fixed output frequency from an inverter?
 thanks

Brochure [here](http://h2flow.net/h2flow/assets/File/iG5A_E%282012_01%29.pdf). 
Manual [here](http://h2flow.net/h2flow/assets/File/iG5A_manual_V2_4_%20100506.pdf).

Comment: I can't seem to find a decent link to the inverter specification. Can you provide a link to the data sheet?

Comment: Links to manual and brochure added. It's a series of conventional 3-phase VFDs. Some have single phase input.

Comment: http://ebookbrowsee.net/ig5a-datasheet-pdf-d236872035 it's my inverter's datasheet.

Comment: i editted my question in my first topic and i thought i made it more clear!!!!  thanks for your quick answers and useful guidance...

Comment: There seems to be a mismatch between the inverter output voltage and your motor's requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brian Drummond points out, you'd need to use something like a transformer (or transformers if you don't have a 3-phase transformer available) to reduce the mains voltage output of a standard VFD to your aircraft-type requirement.

From a brief scan of the data it seems you can adjust the carrier as high as 15kHz and maybe just set the inverter to use a V*f strategy, so it might well work. The PWM won't make very nice sine waves at the maximum 400Hz output, but it might be good enough.

Comment: i can use my inverter or make my own circuit.what do you suggest me? thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Most inverters let you control the frequency and the magnitude of the 3 phases obtained, however you will never have perfect sinewaves getting out as they are generated by chopping the DC bus at high frequency. Depending on the strategy that is used (there are many PWM strategies, but you can count the main ones on one hand) and the switching frequency, you will have more or less current ripple and that ripple will reflect in terms of vibrations (and also on the DC bus, that's why the head capacitor needs to be well-selected).

It seems your inverters use space vector strategies, so I would recommend you get familiar with them, for example [here](http://et.upt.ro/admin/tmpfile/fileM1224954797file490353adde0d4.pdf) (I didn't read it, but it looks like a good intro).

Comment: i can use my inverter or make my own circuit.what do you suggest me? thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Hmm a bit late, I didn't see that comment. Well like often, if that thing does what you want and is within budget, go for it. If it doesn't or if it's too expensive (considering your time is not a cost, which in fact is), assuming you know know your way with power transistors the main issue would be the highside driver but there are chips for that. The control typically can be done either by space vector within a uC, or comparing 3 sine waves (e.g. lookup tables, filtered) with a sawtooth.